# How can I recreate this meme? I want to cast an image over several objects

Tags: modeling, texturing

How was it done? I can make a bunch of rigidbodies and bake the animation, but how do I apply the texture over the rigidbodies? I'm fairly new to blender by the way.

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EARzmijzC7B3HCoVlSFm9tG92w107MB0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: create the simulation, the coins will fall on the ground, then select all the coins, switch to Edit mode, Unwrap >Project from View, and put the UV islands over the image

Answer (score 0):

Create a plane for the ground, give it a *Physics > Rigid Body > Type > Passive*, create a coin, give it a *Physics > Rigid Body > Type > Active*, give it a material, duplicate (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) it and put all the coins above the plane:

[image]

For the material, create this setup, load the image in the *Image Texture* node:

[image]

Play the animation, the coins fall, when they are all still on the ground, select them all, choose the top orthographic view, switch to *Edit* mode, press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Project from View*. In the *UV Editor* move the UV islands so that they cover the image the way you want:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]